# Summing a column in the same column without a circular reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

In Excel you can sum a whole column with `=SUM(B:B)`.  But of course you can't use that formula in the column you want to sum, because you'll get a circular reference.

Is there an easy way of summing all the values in the column below the current cell, other than hacks such as `=SUM(B2:B65536)`?

For reference here's someone asking the same question on ask.metafilter: http://ask.metafilter.com/65955/ExcelFilter-How-do-I-display-the-sum-within-that-column-without-resulting-in-a-circular-reference-error

The suggestion in that thread of `=SUM(B:B-B1)` is essentially what I'm looking for, if only it actually worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same thread you pointed as a reference, there is a user proposing a UDF to solve the problem. Search for `SUMRANGEWITHEXCEPTION` in the text.

With care you may also follow the Excel 2007 help:

> If you want to keep the circular reference, you can enable iterative
>   calculations but you must determine how many times the formula should
>   recalculate. When you turn on iterative calculations without changing
>   the values for maximum iterations or maximum change, Office Excel
>   stops calculating after 100 iterations or after all values in the
>   circular reference change by less than 0.001 between iterations,
>   whichever comes first. However, you can control the maximum number of
>   iterations and the amount of acceptable change.
>
> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button , click Excel Options, and then click the Formulas category.
> 2. In the Calculation options section, select the Enable iterative calculation check box.
> 3. To set the maximum number of times that Office Excel will recalculate, type the number of iterations in the Maximum Iterations
>      box. The higher the number of iterations, the more time that Excel
>      needs to calculate a worksheet.
> 4. To set the maximum amount of change you will accept between calculation results, type the amount in the Maximum Change box. The
>      smaller the number, the more accurate the result and the more time
>      that Excel needs to calculate a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately neither is what I'd class as "easy" :\

Comment: @therefromhere - Unfortunately, I think these are as easy as it gets. Excel does not provide this functionality, so you either have to build it in yourself (with a UDF), work around it (by allowing circular ref's with a single calculation step) or just build formulas that address the range as per `=SUM(B2:B65536)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in any cell in column B without modification:

```
=SUM(IF(ROW()=1,0,INDIRECT("$B$1:$B$"&ROW()-1,1)),
      IF(ROW()=65536,0,INDIRECT("$B$"&ROW()+1&":$B$65536")))
```

Note: This is for Excel versions earlier than 2007.

Comment: you are assuming a 65536 maximum, which is not the case in newer versions of Excel.

Comment: @törzsmókus, thanks, edited in note.  I don't know the new number off the top of my head, so feel free to add it to the note if you do.